# TypeORM OneToMany filter in relations not effect to result

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typescript, typeorm

I have two tables:

```
@Entity('Reviews')
class Review {
  ...
  @OneToMany((type) => MapCategory, map => map.review)
  public categories: MapCategory[];
}
```

And:

```
@Entity('MapCategories')
export class MapCategory {
  ...
  @ManyToOne(type => Review, (review) => review.categories)
  public review: Review;
}
```

When I try the filter on `'categories'` but the result doesn't filter `'categories'` following the key that I already push.

```
const items = await this.reviewRepository.findAndCount({
  relations: ['categories'],
  where: {
    categories: {
      id: 1
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 10):

We need to use `queryBuilder` for cases like this since `find` doesn't allow filtering relations:

```js
const items = await reviewRepository.createQueryBuilder("review")
    .leftJoinAndSelect("review.categories", "category")
    .where("category.id = :id", { id })
    .getManyAndCount()
```

Answer (score 5):

I prefer to avoid query builder when possible.

There's a workaround for filtering based on relation fields for `findOne()`/`find()` methods that I've discovered recently. The problem with filtering related table fields only exists for `ObjectLiteral`-style `where`, while string conditions work perfectly.

Assume that we have two entities – `User` and `Role`, user belongs to one role, role has many users:

```js
@Entity()
export class User {
  name: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => Role, role => role.users)
  role: Role;
}

@Entity()
export class Role {
  @OneToMany(() => User, user => user.role)
  users: User[];
}
```

Now we can call `findOne()`/`find()` methods of `EntityManager` or repository:

```js
roleRepository.find({
  join: { alias: 'roles', innerJoin: { users: 'roles.users' } },
  where: qb => {
    qb.where({ // Filter Role fields
      a: 1,
      b: 2
    }).andWhere('users.name = :userName', { userName: 'John Doe' }); // Filter related field
  }
});
```

You can omit the `join` part if you've marked your relation as an eager one.

Comment: Could you clarify what `a` and `b` are referring to?

Comment: I have a OneToOne relationship in my case, and it won't accept the syntax when I type it, or will simply return all my results. Maybe things have evolved since?