# TypeORM, Query entity based on relation property

Tags: typeorm

I would like to query an entity based on a related property, for instance:

```
const x = await repo.findOne({ name: 'foo', parent: { name: 'foo' }});
```

but it aways returns a null when I query by its related `parent`

I alread added  : `relations: ['parent']`, already set relation as `{eager:true}`

When I Query by `parent: {id: X}` it works. but I must query by its name.

What should I do to get this query working in TypeORM

It would be similar to:

select * from entity inner join parent ... where entity.name = 'foo' and parent.name = 'foo'

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`find`/`findOne` doesn't allow filtering by nested relation properties. Go for `QueryBuilder` instead with something like

```js
const x = await repo.createQueryBuilder("foo")
    .innerJoinAndSelect("foo.parent", "parent")
    .where("parent.name = :name", { name })
    .getOne()
```

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57465674/1763012) for a similar question.

**Edit:** querying by relations is now supported in `typeorm >= 0.3`. See the [release notes](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/releases/tag/0.3.0) for details.

Comment: It was already implemented I think. See https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2707
The accepted answer should be updated.

Answer (score 11):

There's a workaround for filtering based on relation fields for `findOne()`/`find()` methods that I've discovered recently. The problem with filtering related table fields only exists for `ObjectLiteral`-style `where`, while string conditions work perfectly.

Assume that we have two entities – `User` and `Role`, user belongs to one role, role has many users:

```js
@Entity()
export class User {
  name: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => Role, role => role.users)
  role: Role;
}

@Entity()
export class Role {
  @OneToMany(() => User, user => user.role)
  users: User[];
}
```

Now we can call `findOne()`/`find()` methods of `EntityManager` or repository:

```js
roleRepository.find({
  join: { alias: 'roles', innerJoin: { users: 'roles.users' } },
  where: qb => {
    qb.where({ // Filter Role fields
      a: 1,
      b: 2
    }).andWhere('users.name = :userName', { userName: 'John Doe' }); // Filter related field
  }
});
```

You can omit the `join` part if you've marked your relation as an eager one.

Comment: Does anyone know how to say the `qb` property type to fix the type missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @btd1337 `WhereExpression` is what you need

Comment: `join` is now deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

I know this answer would be irrelevant as at when it's needed but for further purposes.
the `typeorm^0.3 above` can now make such query directly just as you want it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the repo pattern:

```
const data = await this.repo.findOne({
    where: {
        parent: {
            name: 'some name',
            // id: Not(IsNull()), // parent (not)exist - this can helpful for someone
        },
    },
    // relations: ['parent'], // if you need this relation
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to get a list of `id` in the parent first.

```js
const searchTerm = 'foo'
const parents = await parentRepo.find({name:searchTerm})
const parentIdList = parents.map(parent=>parent.id)
const x = await repo.find({ where:[{name: searchTerm}, {parent: In(parentIdList)}]});
```

This will give you all the childs whose name is 'foo' or whose parent's name is 'foo'.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative, without having to add the `.where`

```
const x = await repo.createQueryBuilder("foo")
    .innerJoinAndSelect("foo.parent", "parent", "parent.name = :name", { name })
    .getOne()
```