# TypeORM: findOne with "relations" and "where" condition applied on relations - EntityColumnNotFound: No entity column was found

Tags: typeorm

In the project setting, I have 2 entities: `Organization` and `Issue`. One such "organization" has many "issues" belonging to it.
`Issue` has a column named `status` and the values are "Done", "In Progress", "Rejected", etc.

Given an `organizationId`, I am trying to find the organization with all its issues, except for those whose status is 'Done'.

Organization:

```
class Organization extends BaseEntity {

... other code 

  @OneToMany(
    () => Issue, 
    issue => issue.dstOrg, 
  )
  receivedIssues: Issue[]; 

}
```

Issue:

```
class Issue extends BaseEntity {

  ... other code 

  @Column('varchar')
  status: IssueStatus;

}
```

Some helper code:

```
type EntityConstructor = typeof Organization | typeof User | typeof Issue | ... 

const findEntityOrThrow = async <T extends EntityConstructor>(
  Constructor: T,
  id: number | string,
  options?: FindOneOptions,
): Promise<InstanceType<T>> => {
  const instance = await Constructor.findOne(id, options);
  if (!instance) {
    throw new EntityNotFoundError(Constructor.name);
  }
  return instance;
};
```

If the query does not limit the `status` of `Issue`s:

```
  const organizationId = 1; 

  const organization = await findEntityOrThrow(Organization, organizationId, {
    relations: ['receivedIssues'], 
  });

  console.log(organization.receivedIssues)
```

It works well. `organization` now contains a `receivedIssues` field and it contains all the issues.

However, the code that does the complete query fails:

```
  const organizationId = 1; 

  const organization = await findEntityOrThrow(Organization, organizationId, {
    relations: ['receivedIssues'], 
    where: { 
      receivedIssues: {
        status: Not('Done')
      }
    }
  });

  console.log(organization.receivedIssues)
```

This throws an error:

```
EntityColumnNotFound: No entity column "receivedIssues" was found.
```

Why am I missing?

---

Second Question:

If I do not use the helper function and use `findOne()` directly:

```
  const organization = await Organization.findOne(organizationId, {
    relations: ['receivedIssues'], 
    where: { 
      receivedIssues: {
        status: Not('Done')
      }
    }
  }) 

  const allReceivedIssues = organization.receivedIssues;
```

I get this error:

```
src/controllers/organizations.ts:71:29 - error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.

71   const allReceivedIssues = organization.receivedIssues;
```

How can I fix this one if I want to use `findOne()` directly instead of the helper function?

Comment: (1) You cannot filter based on relation properties. More info at (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57647558/typeorm-query-entity-based-on-relation-property). (2) `findOne` has a chance of returning undefined if it can't find anything. You can either do `organization!.receivedIssues` if you're certain it will always be defined or, safer, `organization?.receivedIssues || []`. You might also just do `if (!organization) { return 'Error'; }` or whatnot before you continue.